# how to set the path to phones internal memory while downloading file?

Tags: android, android-studio, filepath

> I am developing an Android application that can download .mp3 files.
>   The path i set for downloading files is
>   `"/sdcard/downloadedfile.mp3"`. It is going to sdcard

. 
I want to set path to internal memory of the device. So that devices which is not having sdcard should go defaultly to the internal memory ..

Can anyone find a solltion for me ..>?

Comment: /sdcard in NOT the path to a removable micro SD card. It is external memory of the device. NOT a micro SD card.

Comment: But then it is still a bad idea to hard code that path. Use the Answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Android Developer Trainee

I think u can try this :

```
String fileName="name.mp3";
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/floderName/");

if (!folder.exists()) {
    try {
        folder.mkdirs();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Default Save Path Creation Error:" + folder);
    }
}

File logFile = new File(folder, fileName);
if (!logFile.exists()) {
    try {
        logFile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Default Save Path Creation Error:" + logFile);

    }
}
```

By the way,
please do not forget to add permission and runtime permission on android6.0

Answer (score 1):

As internal storage locations are permissions protected and any location that you would provide would be accessible only to your application.You can do like this.

(1) Supply a file path on "external" storage this is what you are doing right now , when it completes, copy to internal storage, and then delete the file on external storage.

(2) Create a ContentProvider which DownloadManager can write to and give it a URI that corresponds to this ContentProvider. The ContentProvider that you implement can write the file to internal storage since it will run in the context of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code for your internal storage file:

```
String songname= "Song_Name" ;
File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File.createTempFile(
                songname,  /* prefix */
                ".mp3",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
```

and don't forget to get permission to write storage.

Comment: Could you tell me how to create a newfolder inside the memory and store that file in it ?

Comment: in storageDir varibale add "/myfoldername" to make your specific directory

Comment: Will it create a new folder if not present ?/

Comment: yup. try it. replace "myfoldername" with your project name